# How to replace single forward slashes with single backward slashes

Tags: python-3.x

Consider a python variable containing an arbitrary string with some forward slashes. I would like
to replace every forward slash in the string with a backward slash. These forward slashes appear
in the input string not in the context of a path separator.

I cannot find a way to do this replacement using python's string 'replace' method.

Using a single backslash as the second argument produces syntax error as the single backslash
escapes the terminating quote

```
>>> s = 'a26/n//3@5'
>>> s
'a26/n//3@5'
>>> s.replace('/', '\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s.replace('/', '\')
                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Using two single backslashes in the replacement string produces two backslashes in output string

```
>>> s.replace('/', '\\')
'a26\\n\\\\3@5'
```

The replaced string should contain

```
a26\n\\3@5
```

Comment: "Using two single backslashes in the replacement string produces two backslashes in output string" No, it odesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're seeing is the `repr` representation of the string.

```
>>> s = 'a26/n//3@5'
>>> s
'a26/n//3@5'
>>> s.replace('/', '\\')
>>> s
>>> 'a26\\n\\\\3@5' # repr representation ('\' as '\\')
```

To get your expected output you should `print` the string:

```
>>> new_s = s.replace('/', '\\')
>>> print(new_s)
>>> a26\n\\3@5
```

Edit: Fixed typo

Comment: There's an extra `)` after replace functions ends.

Comment: If the interpreter calls repr method to display, it is not clear why these two statements produce different output
 >>> new_s
'a26\\n\\\\3@5'
>>> repr(new_s)
"'a26\\\\n\\\\\\\\3@5'"
Also, print(new_s) is not same as new_s.__str__(), otherwise, we would have gotten same output in these statements below
>>> print(new_s)
a26\n\\3@5
>>> new_s.__str__()
'a26\\n\\\\3@5'